# Horizontal collection view has space above cell. How to remove it?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, insets

I have collection view with cells I'm presenting horizontally + paging enabled. However I have above cell space that I cant remove (green on screenshot - collection view background). Size of cell is same as containers frame. For better understanding what I mean check screenshot. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

`automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` doesn't works for me
`[self.calendarView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0)];` works but I don't know how to get these -64 programatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to implement these methods below and set zero insets and spacings?

You also need to check if the size of the cell is appropriate, may be the way you see the top spacing is the only way layout engine can put the cell. Please, check what size is set as expected

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've came across similar issue many times.

When a UIScrollView or its subclass, e.g. UITableView and UICollectionView, is the first child of viewController.view, it will get a unexpected contentInset.

My solution:

- If there are other siblings of UIScrollView, make one of
  non-UIScrollView as first child.
- If there is no other siblings, add a dummy UIView as the first child, and either hide the UIView or set the height to 0